# Eclipse key bindings restored to default upon startup

Tags: eclipse, key-bindings

I have a problem with custom keybindings in eclipse, since it seems i can't find anyone with the same problem i guess i am the one missing something.

When i define customised keybindings in Windows->preference then General->keys, it works just fine. (exemples: changinq redo from ctrl+y to ctrl+shift+z and unbinding ctrl+art+p).

the problem: When i restart the eclipse ide, those bindings are reset.

I thought my workspace was corrupt so i tried on a fresh eclipse install with newly created workspace and project... same thing.

runing eclipse neon (4.6) but problem was also on eclipse mars (4.5.2). 
all under windows 7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I know what i missed:

Oomph "preference recorder". (tadaaa).
(in windows->prefereces, then Oomph->setup tasks->preference recorder.)

It is strange that i never bumped into this before. I had this probleme for weeks and "googled" a lot about "eclipse key bindings", but only found out when i clicked on "Review IDE configuration settings - enable preference recorder" on the new neon Welcome view.

Anyway, Problem solved.